# Convert spinner value to string to use in php

Tags: php, android, json

**Java file**

```
public class CreateScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,e6,e7;
    Button b1,b2;
    Spinner s1,s2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_screen);
        final Intent i = getIntent();

        String vno = i.getStringExtra("vno");
        String com = i.getStringExtra("com");
        e1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText8);
        e2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText9);
        e3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText10);
        e4=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText11);
        e5=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText12);
        e6=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText13);
        e7=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText14);

        e1.setText(vno);
        e2.setText(com);
        s1=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        String[] items = new String[]{"RAW MATERIAL", "FINISHED MATERIAL", "SEMI FINISHED MATERIAL"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, items);
        s1.setAdapter(adapter);
        final   String matgrp = adapter.toString();

        s2=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        String[] item = new String[]{"INR", "USD", "MYR","JPY", "SGD"};

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, item);
        s2.setAdapter(adapter1);

        final String currency = adapter1.toString();
        b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.save);
        b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.home);

        b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(CreateScreen.this,MaterialMenu.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            InputStream is =null;
            String result1 =null;

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String a = e1.getText().toString();
                String b = e2.getText().toString();
                String c = e3.getText().toString();
                String d = e4.getText().toString();
                String z = e5.getText().toString();
                String f = e6.getText().toString();
                String g = e7.getText().toString();

                ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("materialnumber", a));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("companycode", b));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("desc", c));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mattype", matgrp));

                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("matgroup", d));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("baseunit", z));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("priceunit", f));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("orderunit", g));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("curr",currency));

                try {
                    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/android/create.php");
                    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    is = entity.getContent();

                    android.util.Log.e("log_tag", "connection success ");

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    android.util.Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connection fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                try {
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    String line = null;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                    is.close();

                    result1 = sb.toString();


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    android.util.Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
                }
                try
                {
                    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(result1);
                    String w = object.getString("re");
                    if(w.equals("Material Created successfully"))
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), w, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent i = new Intent(CreateScreen.this, Menu.class);

                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), w, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "JsonArray failed to load", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });
    }
```

**logcat**

> value cannot be converted to string

How do I need to rewrite this code to convert the spinner value to a string to be used in JsonObject and in PHP?

Comment: Do post the full logs. :)

Comment: Where do you want to pass spinner value?

Comment: Can anyone check and update me the working code....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Adapter class.

Ex :

```
public class AmenityListAdapter extends SomeAdapter(BaseAdapter, ArrayAdapter etc etc) {

@Override
public String toString() {
   StringBuffer strBuf = "";
   for(String myarr:Items) {
       strBuf.concat(myarr+",");
   }
   return strBuf.toString;
}
}
```

Comment: Can u insert this code in my code above so that i can get a clear idea

Comment: It cannot be insert in your above code, because in your code you are using Android existing Adapter classes.

You need to create your custom adapter (by extending Adapter class) then inside that custom Adapter class you need to override your toString() method.
I've mentioned the custom adapter in my above code.
public class AmenityListAdapter extends SomeAdapter. Here AmenityListAdapter is your custom adapter which extends Some adapter class (ex: BaseAdapter or ArrayListAdapter). Inside that you can override toString Class.

Comment: Lets take your below code line:
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, item);
        s2.setAdapter(adapter1);

replace this line with 
AmenityListAdapter adapter1 = new AmenityListAdapter(your parameters);

And Then :
        s2.setAdapter(adapter1);
        final String currency = adapter1.toString();

This will return your desired output.

Comment: adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.mat_grp,android.R.layout.simple_spi‌​nner_dropdown_item); adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); s1.setAdapter(adapter); s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() { @Override public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) { final String matgrp = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString(); } how to access matgrp as global

Answer (score 0):

Here:

> final String currency = adapter1.toString();

In this line toString() method return string representation  of `adapter1` `ArrayAdapter` object instead of selected value from Spinner.

Get selected value from `Spinner` as:

```
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("curr",s2.getSelectedItem().toString()));
```

do same for getting value from Spinner `s1`.

Comment: 05-20 14:40:08.490 5687-5687/com.example.raahulanand.materialmaster E/log_tag: Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
05-20 14:40:10.502 5687-5751/com.example.raahulanand.materialmaster E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xa17b0650

Comment: nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("curr",s2.getSelectedItem().toString()));    still showing error

Answer (score 0):

Override toString method inside adapter class

```
@Override
public String toString() {
   return super.toString();
}
```

Comment: where to add this @Override
public String toString() {
   return super.toString();
} code

Comment: adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.mat_grp,android.R.layout.simple_spi‌​nner_dropdown_item); adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); s1.setAdapter(adapter); s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() { @Override public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) { final String matgrp = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString(); } how to access matgrp as global

Answer (score 0):

remove these code.

final   String matgrp = adapter.toString();
final String currency = adapter1.toString();

and use setOnItemClickListner() method for spinner there you can get parent variable by using the variable you can get the string using parent.getItemAtPosition().

Comment: adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.mat_grp,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        s1.setAdapter(adapter);
        s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                final String matgrp = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

            }     how to access matgrp as global .